# where is the mistake about this command？

Tags: java, maven, sakai, ojdbc

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.sakaiproject.nakamura \
    -D artifactId=org.sakaiproject.nakamura.ojdbc \
    -Dversion=CURRENT-VERSION -Dpackaging=jar \
    -Dfile=maven-launchpad-plugin-2.0.10.jar \
    -Durl=D:\sakai3\nakamura \
    -DrepositoryId=D:\sakai3\nakamura
```

Comment: The repositoryId must be an Id and not a path. Usually a id from your settings.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that the Maven options should go before the goal.  At least, that is what `mvn --help` tells me.

Also, there is an inconsistency in the 2nd `-D` option.

Comment: I don't believe that the order of options/goals is a problem. When you [create projects from an archetype](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html) you often place the goal before the options. But I think your observation regarding the second `-D` option is correct.

Comment: The ordering of options/goals does not matter. you are correct on the second `-D` with the space. Additionally the repositoryId should be an ID of one of the repositories in the user's `settings.xml`